# Pandas - Sample all rows of N unique users/ids

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to sample 1000 unique users within a data. These can be any 1000 users. But I want to extract all rows for the 1000 unique users.

Input

| User_ID | Ship Date |
| --- | --- |
| A454 | 8/2/2019 |
| A454 | 9/2/2019 |
| G658 | 9/2/2019 |
| G658 | 9/2/2019 |

```
from random import sample
df['User_ID'].sample(n=1000, random_state=1)
```

I tried the above code, but this just gives the unique IDs and not all rows for 1000 unique users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, get the `unique` values, `sample` and slice with `isin` and boolean indexing:

```
from random import sample

out = df[df['User_ID'].isin(random.sample(list(df['User_ID'].unique()), 1000))]
```

Comment: I get an error "sample() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n'

Comment: sorry, there is no `n=`

Comment: TypeError: Population must be a sequence or set.  For dicts, use list(d).

Comment: see edit (I checked now, it works)